# How to connect a Python Flask backend to a React front end ? How does it work together?

Tags: python, reactjs, flask

I am making a website. And I want to know how to connect React js to my Flask back end. I have tried searching online but unfortunately it was not what I am looking for. If you know how to do it please recomend me some resources. And I also want to know the logic of how Flask and React work together.

Comment: Through http(s) protocol, use fetch in react side, and listen to routes in flask site...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Flask is a backend micro-service and react is a front-end framework. Flask communicates with the database and makes the desired API hit points. The backend listens for any API request and sends the corresponding response as a JSON format. So using React you can make HTTP requests to the backend.

For testing purposes have the backend and frontend separated and communicate only using the REST APIs. For production, use the compiled js of React as static files and render only the index.html of the compiled react from the backend.

P.S: I personally recommend Django rest framework over flask if you are planning to do huge project.

Comment: @Themaster follow the video below to see and understand the code:https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YW8VG_U-m48&ab_channel=JoranBeasley

Comment: I am just making small projects